# How to create CSS lines for a background section?

Tags: css

I would like to create a section on my website with these vertical lines on the background. How can I accomplish this with CSS? here is the example.

https://www.aanikabio.com/

Many thanks

Comment: See this: https://www.magicpattern.design/tools/css-backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

You can use background lines

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(1*100%/8),
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(2*100%/8),
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(3*100%/8),
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(4*100%/8),
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(5*100%/8),
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(6*100%/8),
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(7*100%/8);
  background-size:1px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<html>
</html>
```